# Can I use SQLCipher for commercial applications that users need to buy from Google APP

Tags: android, sqlcipher

I am developing application for commercial use. This APP will be made available in Google App for certain cost. I want to use SQLCipher to store encrypted data. Can I use SQLCipher for commercial applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, SQLCipher can be used in commercial applications, but you must abide by the terms of [the license](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/license/), including reproduction of the copyright statements.

Comment: On some of the web sites, it is mentioned that "Apps using SQLCipher are restricted from export/distribution in certain countries and require additional export registration with the US government if the app is distributed outside the United States because SQLCipher contains strong encryption. The Play Store asks about US export law compliance when you publish an app. This can be a gotcha when using SQLCipher for developers who are unaware" Does this mean that I can not use it for Apps in Asia continent.

Comment: https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/export-requirements-for-applications-using-sqlcipher/47

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Even I am confused. I have used SQLCipher in iOS app and there is not any compliance issue. But in case of android, people are saying it it mandatory.
Related Link - https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/export-requirements-for-applications-using-sqlcipher/47